# Get second highest salary, return null if no second highest

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Null must be returned if:
- There are less than 2 rows in table
- There isn't a second highest salary because everyone has the same salary

Everything I look up seems to be aimed towards older versions of Sql Server

```
DECLARE @find int = (Select COUNT(*) from Employee);

IF (@find = 1)
    select null as 'SecondHighest'
else
    select Salary as 'SecondHighest' 
    from Employee
    order by Salary desc
    offset 1 rows fetch next 1 rows only;
```

I have managed to return null if there is less than 2 columns, although I think there may be a better way to do this.
However, I can't fix the second problem:
"There isn't a second highest salary because everyone has the same salary"

Comment: You could find highest salary with a query, and a salary which is less than highest in a subquery. If there is no second highest, I guess it will be automaticallly turned into null.

Comment: @alx Unfortunately, it does not automatically become null, it is just empty (no rows). I would like 1 row with null

Comment: Do you mean "less than 2 **rows**"?

Comment: See my reply below, it seems to output exactly what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a similar approach to @alx (which was nice and simple btw, so +1) but it will be easier to generalise to pick the nth highest salary:

```
SELECT MAX(Salary)
FROM
(
  SELECT Salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS Rank
  FROM Employee
) E
WHERE (Rank = 2);
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `ISNULL()` instead of `MAX()` in the SELECT line without changing the rest of your solution?

Comment: Given an one-entry table, I wanted to get it return a table with Null (like [this](https://i.postimg.cc/bwS4vfft/2020-10-27-at-12-32-14.png)) but only got a zero row table returned like ([this](https://i.postimg.cc/xCZK8h2X/2020-10-27-at-12-33-15.png)).

Answer (score 5):

Look at this approach: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfb2cf/3

Here is the query:

```sql
select max(Salary) from Employee where Salary < (select max(Salary) from Employee);
```

And here is the data:

```sql
create table Employee (Id int, Salary int);
insert into Employee values
(1, 100),
(2, 200),
(3, 300);
```

The query outputs `200` which is the correct answer. I guess it applies to SQL server too.

For edge case with one record it outputs `null`, i.e. single row with `null` inside, not a zero rows result.